# Can't access a file with a specific format in wwwroot

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, static-files, asp.net-core-staticfile

I have a `Asp.Net Blazor` project. I can access files in a normal format like `.svg`!
There is a file in `.riv` format that I can't access that file.

[image]

I can see all of the static file in this dashboard.

[image]

And then I can access to a file in a normal format like `c-sharp-icon.svg`

[image]

But I cant access to this file in `.riv` format.

[image]
[image]

This is my StaurtUp config for access to static files.

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseDirectoryBrowser();
```

For more information about .riv format: (https://rive.app/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-standard-content-types), only about 400 file types are served by default.

You could use the ServeUnknownFileTypes
parameter of UseStaticFiles (which is discouraged) or manually specify additional file types with their content type as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#fileextensioncontenttypeprovider).